# Increase query parameter until LIMIT is reached

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find the first 5 runners who ran under 1`km`, but if there are less than 5 runners who satisfy that condition, then increment `km` by 1 until the `LIMIT` of 5 is satisfied.

The only caveat is that if 2 or more results are discoverd upon incrementing `km`, the result with the higher `score` should be returned, even if the other result had a lower `km_run`.

The final result set should be ordered by score.

`Runners`

```
id   runner   km_run   score
 1     mary      3.5    0.55
 2     anna      1.5    0.95
 3     john      6.5    0.90
 4     bill      1.5    0.15
 5     jess      6.2    0.35
 6     jack      2.5    0.75
```

I tried using a subquery to first return the table ordered by `score`, and then placing a `LIMIT` on the outer query.

```
SELECT runner, km_run, score 
FROM runners
WHERE runner IN 
(SELECT runner FROM runners
ORDER BY score DESC)
ORDER BY km_run LIMIT 5
```

But this just returns the 5 runners with lowest `km`.

**Instead, I want exactly this:**

```
 id   runner   km_run   score
  2     anna      1.5    0.95
  3     john      6.5    0.90
  6     jack      2.5    0.75
  1     mary      3.5    0.55
  5     jess      6.2    0.35
```

Please note a few things:

- Results are sorted by descending score
- ID 3 and 5 are returned but not ID 4

This is because only 4/5 results are discovered until the `6-7 km` interval in which 2 results are then found. Both of these 2 results have superior scores than ID 4, hence their inclusion.

---

```
 Between     Results
  0-1 km        0
  1-2 km        2
  2-3 km        1   
  3-4 km        1    --> here we have 4/5 results required
  4-5 km        0
  5-6 km        0
  6-7 km        2    --> now we have 6, but we only want the 5 w/ best score
```

**Setup Queries:**

```
CREATE TABLE runners(
 id SERIAL,
 runner VARCHAR, 
 km_run DECIMAL,
 score DECIMAL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, score)
VALUES ('mary', 3.5, 0.55);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, score)
VALUES ('anna', 1.5, 0.95);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, score)
VALUES ('john', 6.5, 0.90);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, score)
VALUES ('bill', 1.5, 0.15);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, score)
VALUES ('jess', 6.2, 0.35);
INSERT INTO runners (runner, km_run, score)
VALUES ('jack', 2.5, 0.75);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all the runners who have rank 5 or better, where the rank is based on the truncated `km_run`. Then get the 5 of those with the best score.

In SQL:

```
SELECT runner, km_run, score
FROM (SELECT runner, km_run, score,
             rank() OVER (ORDER BY floor(km_run))
      FROM runners) AS q
WHERE rank <= 5
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 5;

 runner | km_run | score 
--------+--------+-------
 anna   |    1.5 |  0.95
 john   |    6.5 |  0.90
 jack   |    2.5 |  0.75
 mary   |    3.5 |  0.55
 jess   |    6.2 |  0.35
(5 rows)
```

The query is not very efficient, because it has to scan the whole `runners` table. But that is hardly avoidable with your requirement — how many table rows we need to scan is not immediately clear.

Comment: Wouldn't this bring runner #4 into the result, which was explicitly not wanted?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't read the small print. My updated answer should cover that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks Laurenz but this in fact brings #4 (bill) into the results unfortunately. Please see my edited answer with your suggestions at the bottom. I had to specify all 3 columns in the inner `SELECT` to get the query to run.

Comment: Sorry about the missing columns. You say you are "trying to find the first 5 runners" and now you say you want to have 6 of them. If you want the 5 with the lowest `km_run`, then put `ORDER BY km_run` into the inner query. My answer is based on your request "now we have 6, but we only want the 5 w/ best score". This is what my answer provides.

Comment: Your answer returns bill as a result, which has a score of `0.15`. Since we have 6 and want the best 5 scores, why is it returning `0.15`? It's the worst of 6.

Comment: Please see my table where I say "Instead, I want exactly this:". That should be the reference for a solution, perhaps I'm describing it poorly, although I'm not sure how else to say it.

Comment: In other words: Priority to find rows initially should be to identify lowest `km_run` rows with the highest `score`. Barring sufficient results to satisfy the `LIMIT` within that `km_run` interval, priority should instead be given to highest `score` results identified within the next interval of `km_run`. Once the `LIMIT` is reached, the results should be `ORDER BY score DESC`. Following this logic, `bill` is excluded as soon as the higher scored runners are identified in their interval. Though `bill` would have stayed included had our `LIMIT` only been 4.

Comment: That's it! I would have struggled long and hard with this. Thank you so much. I'll deep dive into understanding it now but would you mind briefly explaining what the query does? The `rank()` term seems crucial here. +1

Comment: Just run the subquery by itself, then you will understand what `rank()` does. It is like the rank in a competition - if there are two winners, the second place is left empty.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I just noticed your comment about the inefficiency of the query. The number of rows could be upwards of 50,000, columns of 50. This query will be run very, very often so I need it as fast as possible. How else does one accomplish my task without the above approach though?

Comment: Add an `ORDER BY km_run` and a `LIMIT 100` to the inner query and hope that all your desired results are among the first 100 (which they most likely are).